# Calculate the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am given the limit $  \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}    $.

As far as I am concerned $ \ln x \rightarrow - \infty   $ and $\sqrt{x}\rightarrow 0 $ so I got $[\frac{-\infty}{0}]$ . What should I do next? Should I transform it and then use  de l'Hospital rule? $[\frac{-\infty}{0}]$ is not indeterminate form so how should I deal with this?

Comment: Something big and negative divided by something small and positive is ...

Comment: @DavidMitra Is this $-\infty$ ? :D

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}*\ln x \rightarrow (\infty*-\infty) = -\infty $$

Comment: I've downvoted because I think this answer may prompt undesirable ways to think about infinity. Please reconsider this explanation.

Comment: Edited, hope I understood what you meant.

Comment: What would the undersirable ways be? Just curiosity...

Comment: I am upvoting this answer specially to balance the downvotes, despite the fact that I don't like that $\;\infty\cdot(-\infty)=-\infty\;$ thing: it is basically correct.

Comment: -1. You can´t take the product rule of limits here: "if you have a limit of a finite products of functions, and **the limit of each function exists** then the limit of the product is the product of the limits."

Comment: The little right arrow sems to indicate that that is **not** what Genadi did, @dwarandae . He seems  to be indicating simply that the product of a sequence diverging to plus infinite times a sequence diverging to minus infinite is minus infinite, which of course is true. Your downvote seems to be a little too rushed...and the theorem you quote talks of **finite** limits. A limit can exist but be infintie (this couldbe a matter of definition)

Comment: Although the meaning of what has been written in terms of infinity is clear to people well versed in calculus, for beginners it is a very great distraction and the primary source of confusion. It would be better to add a short proof of the statement "if $f(x) \to \infty$ and $g(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to a$ then $f(x)g(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to a$." The way there are rules of algebra of limits in the finite case, there are some rules for handling the limits like $\pm\infty \times \pm\infty, \infty + \infty$ which have much simpler proofs than the corresponding finite versions.